# Console log not printing variable from function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, return-value, console.log

Trying to print the variable 'randomWord' to console.log, but chrome says it is not defined.
It looks like it's defined to me. Why won't it print to the console.log?

```
function strt(){

//get random word from words[] array
var randomWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random()* words.length)];

var wordLength = randomWord.length;


//create a blank boxes or div elements for holding each letter of 
// selected random word
for(i = 0 ; i< wordLength; i++){

var divTag = document.createElement("div");
divTag.id = "div" + i;
divTag.className = 'wordy';
//divTag.innerHTML = randomWord[i];
hangManDiv.appendChild(divTag);

};// end for loop

//disable start button
document.getElementsByName("startB")[0].disabled = true;

return randomWord;

}//end strt()

console.log(randomWord);
```

Comment: Are you calling console.log outside the function ? the randomWord var is defined only in the scope of the function - you need to do this: `console.log(strt());`

Comment: Where are you calling `strt`?

Comment: The variable is defined but it is _local_ to the function `strt()`. Move the `console.log` to before the return statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable `randomWord` is out of the scope. You define the variable inside a function, and then call it *outside* of it.

You should either define the variable out of the function or call it inside of it:

```
function strt(){
   var randomWord;
   ...
   console.log(randomWord);
   return randomWord;
}//end strt()
```

Or

```
var randomWord;
function strt(){
   ...
   return randomWord;
}//end strt()
strt(); // Call the function
console.log(randomWord);
```

For the latter, consider that `randomWord` won't have changed when JS executes the console log function; therefore, it will be null. In other words, you must call the function before you log it.

Comment: "The variable" what? Specificity would be an improvement. :) Also, your second code block needs to show `strt();`. A third, possibly better, option than declaring `randomWord` outside the function would be `console.log(strt());`.

Comment: @ErikE: True, although I'll leave it as it is because it illustrates the point better, as to not confuse others. For example, if one wanted to console.log more than one variable...

Comment: Ok, so I ended up putting the console.log inside the strt() function. It works now. One question though. In the strt() function I'm returning the 'randomword' variable. Why can't I use 'randomWord' outside the strt() function if it's being returned.

Comment: @user1965121: Think of it as a sequence of steps. In your case, the console log occurs *before* the variable is returned. Additionally, for it to work, the variable you make reference to must be in the scope of the call. In other words, you would need to have something like `newvar = strt()` and you would make reference to this new variable rather than the initial one.

Comment: @user1965121 a return value from a function completely disappears if you don't store it into a variable. It doesn't automatically create a window-level/global-level variable of the name `randomWord`. Consider that in your function you could just as easily do `return 'the word is ' + randomWord + '.';`--how could this create a variable in the outer scope and what name would it have? Instead, you need to do `var wordresult; wordresult = strt(); console.log(wordresult);` to get what you're expecting: a variable with the result of the `strt` function's execution as its value.

Comment: @JCOC611 In response to your comment about logging more than one variable, then may I suggest NOT using the same outer variable name `randomWord` as the variable in the inner function scope? I think this collision could really confuse a beginner--they need to see that it is a *different variable*, despite having the same name.