# Printing results of function outside of the local scope

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was wondering how to print the return value of my function outside of the scope of the function. I researched online and found the post below bu this just gave me arr is undefined. Can somebody please point me in the right direction?
[Console log not printing variable from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15694273/console-log-not-printing-variable-from-function)

```
function multiplyAll(arr) {
    var product = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++)
            product = product * arr[i][j];
    }
    //why is the product undefined?
    return product;
}
//modify values below to test code
multiplyAll([
    [60, 60],
    [24, 365]
]);

//console.log("Print results of product" + product);
```

Comment: replace `multiplyAll([[60,60],[24,365]]);` with `var product = multiplyAll([[60,60],[24,365]]);`

Comment: Your function returns a value, but when you actually *call* the function your code ignores that returned value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of just calling `multiplyAll` by itself, you should assign it to a variable like this:

```
var product = multiplyAll([[60,60],[24,365]]);
```

Another thing you can do if you only want to print out the result is to just put the function call inside of your `console.log` call like so:

```
console.log("Print results of product" + multiplyAll([[60,60],[24,365]]));
```